# No useful logging output during system freezes / almost-freezes

Tags: 16.04

I am experiencing occasional system freezes with Ubuntu 16.04 using the Gnome 3 Desktop. The logging output in `/var/log` is not really helpful. There are no files in `/var/crash`. I have not been able to identify a pattern in the last log entries before the freeze. I would like to investigate the problem further or file a bug report, but I ran out of ideas how to track it down. Here are the symptoms (similar to those [Mysterious minutes-long system freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869940/mysterious-minutes-long-system-freeze)):

- The UI freezes **except** the mouse cursor, which still responds with a latency of several seconds (it jumps roughly in the direction of the mouse movement).
- The system usually does not respond to keyboard input. Sometimes I was able to `ctrl-alt-f1` to the console, but I was rarely able to login. I never succeeded to execute a command (e.g. `dmesg`, `sudo init 6`). Even `sysrq-o` would not work.
- The HDD LED is illuminated constantly.
- Judging by the fan speed, the CPU runs under high load.

The only recovery is a hard reset/reboot. I am suspecting that the freezes occured in the following situations:

- High memory usage
- A VirtualBox VM (windows guest) is running or has been running for a while (e.g. several days)

However, the logfiles give no hints in that direction. There are for example no messages of the OOM killer. How should I proceed to identfy the exact error conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a large swap partition made the problem vanish. It seems that under certain conditions the system was running out of memory so quickly that even the OOM killer did not have a chance to run (or its output being logged to a persistent location). However, I did not identify the root cause of the spiking memory usage.